# SerializedProperty avoiding getter?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using getters and setters for variables to avoid checking if they are null. Also I don't need Start() and Awake() functions in most cases.

```
    public Button[] TitlebarButtons
    {
        get { return titlebar_buttons ?? (titlebar_buttons = GetComponentsInChildren<Button>()); }
    }
    private Button[] titlebar_buttons;

    public Color CloseButtonNormalColor
    {
        get { return TitlebarButtons[2].colors.normalColor; }
        set
        {
            ColorBlock temp = ColorBlock.defaultColorBlock;
            temp.normalColor = value;
            temp.highlightedColor = TitlebarButtons[2].colors.highlightedColor;
            temp.pressedColor = TitlebarButtons[2].colors.pressedColor;

            TitlebarButtons[2].colors = temp;
        }
    }
```

And in Editor script I am trying to make CloseButtonNormalColor a Serialized Property:

```
private Title Title;
private SerializedProperty close_button_normal_color;

void OnEnable()
{
    Title = (Title)target;

    close_button_normal_color = serializedObject.FindProperty("CloseButtonNormalColor");
}
```

But when I'm using it, NullReferenceExeption appears.

```
close_button_normal_color.colorValue = EditorGUILayout.ColorField("Normal", close_button_normal_color.colorValue);
```

Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Usually to just exposes properties on inspector you can use

```
[ShowProperty]
public MyProperty {get; set;}
```

and fields

```
[SerializeField]
private myField;
```

Answer (score 0):

i found two "workarounds" for this.

One come from this thread in unity forum:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/using-property-fields-in-custom-editor-when-using-auto-properties.828597/

So, you can:

```
public class ClassToCustomEditor
{
    [field:SerializeField] public int CustomEditorProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your custom editor script:

```
 void OnEnable()
 {
    IsCraftable = serializedObject.FindProperty(
        string.Format("<{0}>k__BackingField", "IsCraftable")
    );
 }
```

for me, in Unity 2020.1.14f1 works like a charm. If you need more details, i suggest you to visit the thread above.

The other work around is create private fields (whose FindProperty find) and then create propeties who access and modify these fields.

Something like:

```
public class MyClassToCustomEditor
{
    [SerializeField] private string itemName;

    public string ItemName
    {
        get { return itemName; }
        set { itemName = value; }
    }
}
```

and then the FindProperty would be able to find it right the way you write it.